# ModuleNotFoundError only when starting by terminal, how to fix?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pywin32

Running the following test script

```
import win32api

print(win32api.EnumDisplaySettings().DisplayFrequency)  # just for testing
```

works absoultely fine out of my IDE PyCharm, but running this script via Terminal using "python test.py" produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does print(sys.path) match both in and out of the IDE PyCharm?

Comment: No it, isn't. PyCharm IDE uses venv (python3.6), Terminal uses globally installed python3.8. Is there a way to start the script in Terminal using the venv?

Comment: Well the issue is different python versions. Do you have win32api installed for both. Can you "pip list" to see what you have installed? If it isn't installed can you "pip install win32api"?

Comment: If you update your path to include anaconda3/bin then your terminal will be running python3.6 instead of python3.8. Updating path in windows is a pain, you have to go into some system setting somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I can solve my problem by this. Thanks a lot!